# How do I get the Crota and Oryx masks?

Tags: destiny

Since the Festival of the Lost started, I've gotten pretty much every mask there is except for Crota and Oryx. Most of them I've gotten multiple times - I'm pretty sure I've been through at least a half-dozen of Petra Venj! This is particularly annoying since the Crota mask is required for one of the FotL quest lines.

Is there something particular that I need to do for the Crota/Oryx masks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all the normal masks are acquired from opening either the rare goodie bag (obtained via filling your candy bag by killing guardians or minions of the darkness while wearing a mask, trading mask items from deconstruction to Eva, or from completing quests) or the legendary goodie bag (acquired at the Eververse Trading Company for silver).

The only mask that is exclusive to the legendary goodie bag is the flaming skull mask. It is purely cosmetic.

Comment: Are the Crota and Oryx masks particularly associated with, or more common to, the Legendary bags perhaps? Or do they just have an extremely low drop rate in comparison to the others? I find it very strange that I still haven't gotten them, in spite of how many duplicates of others I've already thrown away. I mean, RNG is gonna be RNG, but as you increase the number of tries the probability of randomly turning up a desired result at least one time within those attempts comes close enough to 100% that it's actually very *improbable* that you wouldn't.

Comment: What you're describing would only be true over very large timescales. To my knowledge, all of the masks are pretty even in terms of drops. Sorry you're having bad luck with the RNG.

Comment: @Iszi: consider though that if there is a one in a million chance of you not having got either of those two masks (number totally made up) then that means that one in every million destiny players is going to have that problem. Sure, it might be improbable but with the number of players it is likely that somebody has the problem and it is equally likely to be you than anybody else. The thing with RNG is that if you only have a sample size of 1 then you can't say much. I have I think five masks and one of them is oryx so a sample size of two immediately changes the perception.

Comment: Sample size of three: I have received about a dozen and two were oryx.

Comment: The Crota mask finally dropped out of a Rare bag for me sometime last week. Knocked off the quest, and... suddenly lost all motivation (as this was the last Festival quest I had) to participate in the Festival any more. Such a shame.